# Blackboard installation

Tags: installation, environment, blackboard

I worked on Moodle few months ago and I was searching in the past days on a way to install blackboard LMS locally to try it, but I didn't found any link that talks about this.

I thought they were the same way but it was dark so if anyone could give me any help I'll be very thankful.

Comment: did you get anything to start with?

Comment: @BajrangHudda well, all what I found, after a lot of searching, is the link below.‍♂️

Comment: Means you took a licence for this?

Comment: @BajrangHudda Honestly, I was just making a research for it to use it later. But after searching for about a week I guess I stopped with the link below.
So no I didn't took a license.
If you got something else, it'll be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local hosted development environments are available to licensed partners as moneil answered a similar question in https://community.blackboard.com/thread/5846-what-all-things-will-be-needed-to-host-the-blackboard-rest-application-on-local-system